# CSS font-size in pixels: what does it meaure?

Tags: css, fonts, pixel

CSS has font-size that can use "px" pixels.  But what exactly is being measured to be the given pixels?

Take 14px, does that mean that no letter will be over 14 pixels?  Is that the average size of the letter heights? Is that the measurement of the tallest letter?  Or is it an altogether different measure?

Comment: A font usually contains other characters than Latin letters. Some of them will reach above the tallest ascenders or below the deepest descenders of the Latin letters.

So the font size specifies the height of the character box in which all possible glyphs in the font must fit. Latin letters may or may not utilise the full extent of that box.

Comment: @Shah nice comemnt, can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A font usually contains other characters than Latin letters. Some of them will reach above the tallest ascenders or below the deepest descenders of the Latin letters. So the font size specifies the height of the character box in which all possible glyphs in the font must fit. Latin letters may or may not utilise the full extent of that box.

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question:

Stolen from : https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference

> A pixel is a single square 'picture element' (hence pix-el), i.e. a
>   single dot in your image. A 10x10 image is made up of a set of pixels
>   in a grid 10 wide by 10 high, totaling 100 pixels.
>
> The 'point' (pt) on the other hand is a unit of length, commonly used
>   to measure the height of a font, but technically capable of measuring
>   any length. In applications, 1pt is equal to exactly 1/72th of an
>   inch; in traditional print technically 72pt is 0.996264 inches,
>   although I think you'll be forgiven for rounding it up!
>
> How many pixels = 1pt depends on the resolution of your image. If your
>   image is 72ppi (pixels per inch), then one point will equal exactly
>   one pixel.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but I was not asking about points, just pixels. I know the conversion between points and pixels is complicated.  But given a pixel (px), what part of the letter is being measured?  What does 14px mean: the height of the largest letter in pixels?  The bounding height?  Is there any padding?  Sah's comment to my question above got to the core of what I was trying to ask.